# Delete DatagridviewRows using DatagridviewImageColumn

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, sql-delete

I have a `DataGridView` which is bounded to a `DataTable` which have a foreign key to another `DataTable`. I added a `DatagridViewImageColumn` to delete rows from these two `DataTable`. The code I have used is below.

```
private void dechargeDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    switch (dechargeDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
    {
        case "delete":

            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand deleteDechargeCmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Decharge] WHERE NumeroDecharge = @NumDecharge", con);
            deleteDechargeCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumDecharge", dechargeDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());


            SqlCommand deleteLigneDCmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [LigneDecharge] WHERE NumeroDecharge = @Num", con);
            deleteLigneDCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num", dechargeDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());


            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Voulez vous supprimer le Decharge de Livraison?", "Confirm product deletion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {   
                deleteDechargeCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                deleteLigneDCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("le Decharge de Livraison est supprimé avec succées");
                dechargeDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
            }
            else
            {
            }
            con.Close();
            break;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't give any error. It executed perfectly but in reality no rows is deleted from the two tables. I don't know where is the error in this code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to be correct, it must works fine, so check the value of the

parameters may be the cell is not

> dechargeDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()

so try to write the column name like this:

> dechargeDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnName"].Value.ToString()

Comment: Yes you are right i was confusing in the index column because i created columns programmatically. I changed it to the Column Name and it works like a charm. Thanks for help :)